# Contradiction (?): DNA ion mobility vs diffusion constant

Tags: waves, diffusion

There is a certain confusion about DNA ion mobility and diffusion constant in the literature.

Consider double-stranded DNA ions in pure water. DNA ions are negatively charged 
due to phosphoric acid in its structure. DNA **ion mobility** data and **diffusion constant** data seem to contradict each other, unless there's something amiss.

Those 2 quantities should be connected with `Einstein-Smoluchowski` equation:

$\frac{D}{\mu} = \frac{kT}{q}$,

where $D$ is diffusion constant, $\mu$ is ion mobility, $q$ is ion charge, $k$ is Boltzmann constant and $T$ is temperature.

Experimental evidence show that DNA ion mobility increases as DNA length increases until ~400 base pairs, where increase stops (from `Stellwagen, N., Gelfi, C., Righetti, P. G., Biopolymers 1997`):

[image]

This can be rationalized as follows: when DNA is short it can be considered as a rod-like molecule. As its size grows it becomes more of a ball-like, eventually  taking ball shape at ~400 base pairs and after that size of the ball doesn't affect its mobility:

[image]

Let's consider DNAs of length 400 and 4000. Their ion mobilities $\mu$ are even, while their diffusion constants should differ 10-times (from `Einstein-Smoluchowski` equation, considering their charges proportional to the lengths, which is questionable):

$\frac{D_{400}}{\mu_{400}} = \frac{kT}{400}$, $\frac{D_{4000}}{\mu_{4000}} = \frac{kT}{4000}$, $\frac{D_{400}\cdot\mu_{4000}}{\mu_{400}\cdot D_{4000}} = \frac{4000}{400}$, $\frac{D_{400}}{D_{4000}} = 10$.

Experimental measurements of DNA diffusion coefficients are controversial:
`Smithetal et al.` measured it with an indirect technique called “optical chopsticks” and their data are as follows:

```
DNA fragment length     Diffusion coefficient, mkm^2/s
            309 000                               0.14
            216 000                               0.17
             48 502                               0.47
             23 130                               0.66
              9 416                               1.13
              6 557                               1.43
              4 361                               1.94
```

Measurements, compiled from various papers by `Stellwagen et al. in 2001` show this:

[image]

They suggest that "translational diffusion coefficients of DNA decrease as the -0.67 power of molecular weight, over nearly a thousandfold range of molecular weights".

How do I interpret this? Does the charge of DNA change non-linearly with the size of DNA molecule?

Comment: According to [this paper](http://www.researchgate.net/profile/Bernard_Tinland/publication/11825687_Diffusion_coefficient_of_DNA_molecules_during_free_solution_electrophoresis/links/542170de0cf2ce3a91b76644.pdf), "it is often not realised that [$D/\mu=kT/q$] should not be valid during free flow electrophoresis." That seems to be the simplest answer to your question.

Comment: @lemon Thank you so much, the paper and references in it mostly resolved my problem. Please, post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it!